# Need Help removed a 3 way switch and converting to Single Pole with receptacle (in same box) when power comes from Light

Tags: electrical

After my new garage door was installed, I no longer need a 3 way switch (and it had ripped insulation so I pulled it out.

INFO: the Power comes from the light to the switch box.
[image]

Next here was the box wired prior to me pulling out the 3way switch (labeled #3 here).

#1 is power from light into box

[image]

Finally, here is the picture of what I am left with (I took the black wires apart from tape in previous picture) --- I would like to keep the outlet and just have a single pole next to it for a light.

The black and Red from #1 both light up tester as hot --- no other wires have voltage in the box.

[image]

Hopefully, this question makes sense with the photos ----

---

I would like to keep the outlet and a single pole switch in this box.  The #3 switch I am referring to (that I removed) was in another box.

thank;s

rt

FINAL UPDATE -- STILL NEED HELP!!!!!

** I CAPPED OFF BOTH RED WIRES and connected hot black to lamp.  Now I wired the switch and outlet below, and switch is on in both the on or off position..

can anyone help?
Here is the summary

Line 1 -- Black (hot to top screw of switch and top of outlet)
----------White to top of outlet
----------Red -- capped

Line 2 --- black bottom of switch (not hot)
----------White to bottom of outlet
---------- no red

[image]

Comment: It does make sense. You can reuse the switch, but **don't**, because aside from confusion because of the 3-way (which can be dealt with) it is very old (as evidenced by the type of screws), you want to get a "screw to clamp" type so that you don't use the backstabs (horrible) and they allow two wires per screw (so you can chain to the receptacle) and in general easy to use. Is the circuit currently GFCI protected? If not then you will need GFCI for this receptacle, and in any case a new cover - might need to use a mud ring + a standard cover, depending on what you can find to fit the box.

Comment: Yeah, I should have said that -- I got a new single pole switch -- the circuit is GCFI protected at breaker-- I am asking about how to connect wires though ...anyone?

Comment: Great GFCI at the breaker makes things easier here. If it will fit your box, you can get a cover like [this one from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-4-in-W-Steel-Metallic-2-Gang-Exposed-Work-Square-Cover-for-1-Toggle-Switch-and-1-Duplex-Outlet-1-Pack-G1941-UPC/324472720) If you asked me a few weeks ago, I would have written up an answer already. Right now I am sort of [on strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an) and not adding real answers. If Harper or one of the other regulars gives

Comment: an answer you'll be all set. But basically you need to identify always hot, switched hot, neutral (which will always be white but white is not always neutral) and then hot goes to switch and from switch to receptacle (or vice versa), neutral goes to receptacle and switched hot to switch.

Comment: I added a final edit, with a new picture and comments but the switch doesn't turn light on or off --- its on all the time ? any help ? (both reds capped now)

Answer (score 2):

OK.  So let's ignore cable 3, the 3-way switch leg - on that, white was (correctly) always-hot, and black and red were travelers.

Power comes from the lamp, but it comes down to the box in /3 cable.  So either your ancient installation there complied with NEC 2011, or the /3 is so the cable can carry *both* always-hot *and* switched-hot *and* neutral so that power can be carried onward to other places on cable #2.

When that is done, I prefer the following color scheme.

- White = neutral
- Black = *always-hot*; hot when the power hasn't failed.
- Red = *switched-hot* to the lamp.

I'm having trouble discerning this, but it appears they used red for always-hot and black for switched-hot.  I would do it "my way" and make black your always-hot.  On the switch in this box, on its 2 terminals (you don't need to wire ground to the switch) put a black pigtail going to the other blacks; and the red wire.

Up at the lamp, wire the lamp to the neutral bundle, and also to the red wire.

Just FYI, these domed covers also exist.

[image]
[image]

*Those little tangs break off. They have threaded holes, and you use them as self-holding nuts to mount the socket.  This works a bit better than an actual bolt and nut.*

Comment: Wrong cover. Need [one of these](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-4-in-W-Steel-Metallic-2-Gang-Exposed-Work-Square-Cover-for-1-Toggle-Switch-and-1-Duplex-Outlet-1-Pack-G1941-UPC/324472720) for switch + receptacle. But otherwise excellent answer as usual.

Comment: I get everything you said except its both a single pole switch and a standard outlet in the  same box ----

Comment: @richtree sorry, I got confused which switch you were deleting. Just use the same domed cover, though they do make a regular+decora if you needit.

Comment: Update --- I capped the Red wires, and put a new outlet and single pole switch in the receptacle --- only 2 questions remain   #1-- from the second photo in the post --- do I now separate the 2 black wires from the lines labeled 1 and 2 that were on the top screw of the (old) switch?  --- and #2 do I still need that little jumper black wire or is there a better way ? (wago etc)? thanks

Comment: Should be: white x 2 to neutral of light, red (as originally pictured) to hot of light, blacks together (gets power from circuit down to switch. In the switch/receptacle box: black goes to *both* top of switch and hot of receptacle, red goes to bottom of switch, white goes to neutral of receptacle (and neutral on switch if you ever install a smart switch that needs it).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact --- I removed the Red wires at the lamp and the box and just capped them --- do I need to put them back ? thanks

Comment: @richtree Sorry, I forgot you wanted a single switch here to work.  See my edit above.  Use the red wire for switched-hot.

Comment: that worked once I added back the red wires ---- thanks so much for the help here !